# What is an appropriate scale and numPixels for unsupervised classification in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying to do an unsupervised classification based on a sentinel-2 composite. However, I am running quickly into time out and maximum memory problems. I am sure that it has to do with the scale and the numPixels. Looks like I don't really understand the combination of the two and what the sample function really does, since to me a sample of 500 pixels and a scale of 15 should be fine?

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([126.49, 72.38]).buffer(55000);
Map.setCenter(126.49, 72.38, 8);

var sent2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
    .filterDate('2018-07-01', '2018-09-15')
    .filterBounds(roi)

var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');

var extentGSW = gsw.select('occurrence') 
  .clip(roi)
  .unmask(0);

var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.expression(
  "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
  {
    RED: image.select("B4"),
    NIR: image.select("B5"),
    BLUE: image.select("B2")
  }).rename('ndvi');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = sent2.map(addNDVI);


// Mask water
var masked = withNDVI.map(function(img) {
 var mask = extentGSW.lt(50)
 var maskNDVI = img.select('ndvi').gt(0.025);
 var QA60     = img.select('QA60');
 var clouds   = QA60.bitwiseAnd(1<<10).or(QA60.bitwiseAnd(1<<11));
 return img.updateMask(mask).updateMask(maskNDVI).updateMask(clouds.not());
});

var greenest = masked.qualityMosaic('ndvi');

Map.addLayer(greenest.select('ndvi').clip(roi), {min:  0, max: 0.3, palette: ['#8bc4f9', '#c9995c','#c7d270', '#8add60', '#097210']}, "ndvi");

// unsupervised classification

var training = greenest.select("B2", "B3", "B4", "B8", "B11", "B12", "ndvi").sample({
  region: roi,
  scale: 15,
  numPixels: 500
 });


var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(10).train(training);
var result = greenest.cluster(clusterer);

Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always a good idea to export the image you're classifying as an asset, and then classify that asset. Split your script into two, one script that generate your `greenest` image and export, and a second script that do the classification. With this, you can use a scale of 10 meters.

Export script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ddad402c2573002c3b973b7864bb8a40?noload=1

Classification script (enter the asset ID from the export script): https://code.earthengine.google.com/103c6cd26cf041f4a59e0f70ca0c26f1

Comment: Great, thanks! Still wondering what the sample is doing if scale and numPixel is changed. Does it simply mean that the training dataset consists of numPixel samples from the specified region and works on the resolution of scale (e.g. if scale = 10, then by 10 meters)? Is there a general rule for what is appropriate in terms of scale and numPixel (probably depending on the spatial extent)?

Comment: It often makes sense to sample at the scale of your imagery, and never below it (as far as I can figure). How many samples you need will vary from case to case. A good thing of sampling and classifying an asset is that you get really fast feedback on what works and not.